# Cómo crear un comando para una consola CMD de comandos Java?

Tags: java

como hacer que dada la siguiente instrucción por teclado:

`mueve rutaOrigen rutaDestino`

realice la siguiente función:

```
private static void copyFileUsingStream(Path origenPath, Path destinoPath) throws IOException { 
        
        try {
            Files.move(origenPath, destinoPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Creas un JAR y le pones un alias con algún .bat

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algunas cosas que hacer (y estudiar) aquí.

**Primero** necesitará crear un método **main**, este método será el primer método de su programa al que se llamará cuando se ejecute su "aplicación". Este método principal recibirá un **vector de String** que contiene todo lo que se informó en la línea de comando como parámetro.

```
//Si llama al programa con:
//java -jar myapp.jar mueve rutaOrigen rutaDestino
//Entonces tendrás dentro de los argumentos var:
//[mueve], [rutaOrigen], [rutaDestino]
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]); //imprimirá "mueve"
    System.out.println(args[1]); //imprimirá "rutaOrigen"
    System.out.println(args[2]); //imprimirá "rutaDestino"
}
```

**Segundo**, tendrá que tratar los parámetros recibidos, tal vez verificar si existen `if (args != null && args.length > 0)`, si son cadenas válidas, si son su "comando" `if ("mueve".equals(args[0]))` seguido de dos "rutas", verificar si las "rutas" realmente existen `if (new File(args[1]).exists())`, etc. .

**Tercer**, llame a su `copyFileUsingStream` pasando los argumentos que ya trató `copyFileUsingStream(args[1], args[2])`

**Cuarto**, exporte su "aplicación" como un **JAR ejecutable**, busque cómo exportar esto en el IDE que está utilizando.

Después de tener su jar ejecutable, como "**myapp.jar**", puede ir a la línea de comando y ejecutar algo como:

`java -jar myapp.jar mueve rutaOrigen rutaDestino`

Si no quieres escribir `java -jar myapp.jar mueve`, sino que solo quieres escribir `mueve`, necesitarás otro paso.

**Quinto**, en un simple bloc de notas, crea un archivo de texto y renómbralo a `mueve.bat`, dentro de este archivo escribes `java -jar myapp.jar mueve`, guárdalo y ciérralo, copia este archivo mueve.bat a la carpeta `System32` y listo, ahora tienes tu propio comando. Puede ir a la línea de comandos, en cualquier lugar, y simplemente escribir `mueve rutaOrigen rutaDestino`.